# How do I effectively target a specific key-modifier combination in an XKB interpret statement?

Tags: keyboard, xkb

I want to lock a certain modifier (Mod3) when pressing `Control + Caps_Lock`.

```
xkb_compatibility "mod3"
{
    // set Control bit on Control_L
    interpret Control_L {
        action = SetMods(modifiers=Control);
    };
    // try locking Mod3 …
    interpret Caps_Lock+Exactly(Control) {
        action = LockMods(modifiers=Mod3);
    };
};
```

Using `xev -event keyboard` I never saw the `Mod3` bit flipped, even though the `Control` bit was.

I also tried using just a regular `a` instead of `Caps_Lock`, which didn’t change anything.

Further, I tried using `AnyOf(Control)` instead of `Exactly(Control)`.

---

What am I missing?
Could anything else in my XKB map interfere with the above attempt?
Or is my assumption about how the `interpret` statement works just wrong?

Answer (score -4):

Try replacing 'action' with 'actions'.

Comment: I believe `action` is correct. If you have evidence that this is not so, consider updating your answer with references to official documentation and maybe even a working example.

Comment: When looking at the symbols files, the only reference to 'action' that I see are those using 'actions', e.g. `actions[Group1] = [ SetMods(modifiers=NumLock) ]`

Comment: Hmmm... not on my system with X 7.7. I definitely see things like `action = SetMods(modifiers=modMapMods);` in e.g. `X11/xkb/compat/pc`.

Comment: If you have additional information to support your answer, please do not post it in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.